# Browsing and editing saved form data in Firefox

Tags: firefox, forms

Is there a way to browse and edit/delete saved form entries in Firefox?

I know I can:

- Delete all form data, using the *Clear Private Data* dialog;
- [Delete specific entries](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Deleting_autocomplete_entries) in a form using shift-delete when the cursor is over them (*).

I want is way to see all saved entries for a specific keyword, edit them, and easily delete all or selectively.

I expected to find a plugin that does it, but I couldn't find any. Or is there an external tool that manipulates the *formhistory.sqlite* file?

(*) For those of you that don't know this: go to your favorite search engine's search box, and press the down key to see the history. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd> will delete the "current" entry from saved form data.

Comment: Doesn't look like a programming question for me (even if the question is interesting).

Comment: Actually you only need to press delete, not shift-delete (on Windows at least)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The [SQLite Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/addon/sqlite-manager-webext/) extension can open the `formhistory.sqlite` file (as well as any other `.sqlite` file in a Firefox profile folder) and make it available for adding, editing, and deleting records with the simple GUI.

Comment: The link's broken, try: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager-webext/

Comment: For Waterfox Classic: **SQLite Manager** 0.8.3 – in the Classic Add-ons Archive at `caa:addon/sqlite-manager` | https://ca-archive.biz.tm/storage/5/5817/sqlite_manager-0.8.3-tb+sm+fx.xpi

Comment: This may no longer be true after [Firefox Quantum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefox#Firefox_Quantum) (2017). [ESR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefox#Experimental_builds_and_ESR)? Perhaps it is time for an update?

Answer (score 12):

They're stored in an [SQLite](http://sqlite.org/) database in your profile directory (e.g., *C:\Documents and Settings\xxxxx\Application Data\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\xxxxx*), in a file called formhistory.sqlite.

You can download the [SQLite client](http://sqlite.org/download.html) (executable `sqlite`) to browse and edit the database.

Comment: I know about the formhistory.sqlite file (see my question). I was wondering if anyone has already built something to handle it.
If I were to do it - since I have no experience with Firefox extensions I'd probably use Python.

Answer (score 3):

**Update** (as per comment): *No longer true with the new Webextension API. Form History control manages a separate history.*

---

The **[Form History Control](https://addons.mozilla.org/addon/form-history-control/)** extension can remove a specific input and same input from all form history.

Comment: I'm not sure how I'd feel about giving an extension with a note of "This extension isn’t monitored by Mozilla. Make sure you trust the extension before you install it." full access to saved form data - particularly when I'm trying to figure out what's apparently inappropriately saving and autofilling a password (albeit an old one which is causing problems).

Comment: No longer true with the new Webextension API. Form History control manages a separate history.

Answer (score 2):

I develop [Adobe AIR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Integrated_Runtime) applications and use Lita to view their SQLite databases.  I just tried it on the Firefox forms database and I like it better than the Firefox extension.

The good thing about the extension is that it provides easy access to your databases, but once you know where they all are:

**On a Mac:**

`/Users/[yourName]/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/[profileName]`

**On Windows:**

`C:\Documents and Settings\[yourName]\Application Data\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\[profileName]`

Then, I think you're better off using your favorite SQLite client.

For me, on a Mac that's Lita:

http://www.dehats.com/drupal/?q=node/58

*Note*: Lita will also work on Windows and Linux.

Comment: This may no longer be current. E.g., the link is (effectively) broken (it redirects to page with erotic content). And possibly after [Firefox Quantum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefox#Firefox_Quantum) (2017)—which broke a lot of extensions. Perhaps it is time for an update?